callbackUrl not working in auth.js signin
I have set up a next.js app with next-auth.js, authenticating with a custom OIDC identity provider. I'm currently using next-auth version 5.0.0-beta.19, which I believe is part of the proposed migration to auth.js.
Anyway the auth all works fine, with one exception. After signin I'm always redirected back to the homepage even when I specify a callbackUrl option argument to the signIn function. If I debug next-auth's redirect callback I can observe that the url and baseUrl arguments are always the same value (http://localhost:3000).
The component where signin is implemented looks like this:
import { auth, defaultProviderId, signIn, signOut } from "@/auth"

export default async function SignInButton() {
  const authSession = await auth();

    if (authSession?.user) {
        return (
          <form
            action={async () => {
              "use server"
              await signOut();
            }}
          >
          <button type="submit">Sign out {authSession.user.name}</button>
        </form>
        );
    }

    return (
      <form
        action={async () => {
          "use server"
          await signIn(defaultProviderId, {
            callbackUrl: "/this/doesnt/work"
          });
        }}
      >
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    )
}

I don't seem to be doing anything different to other examples. Is there any other code I can share to help identify the issue? Like I say, the authentication itself works fine.

From the docs:
"Once authenticated, the user will be redirected back to the page they started the signin from. If you want the user to be redirected somewhere else after sign in (.i.e /dashboard), you can do so by passing the target URL as redirectTo in the sign-in options."
https://authjs.dev/getting-started/session-management/login
It seems that it is "redirectTo" instead of "callbackUrl"


Thank you. I'd actually found this and tried it earlier but it didn't seem to be working. I now realise it's because I had the redirect callback implemented as async redirect({ baseUrl }): Promise<string> { return baseUrl; } (must have been left over from some tutorial I'd followed) so this was ignoring the url argument which gets set when redirectTo is used in the signin. I was essentially rejecting my own redirect URL! Removing that callback fixed the issue.

Glad I could help. I had my share of issues with Next-auth... I know how annoying it can be sometimes, but luckily that was simple :) cheers

For anyone struggling to get this to work with ie. the Postmark provider. The redirectTo option should be passed along with the formData(!) object for this to work.
So a hidden inputfield with a 'redirectTo' name should do the trick.
